# Azure Function App STDOUT logs to Azure Minitor Logs or some similar service

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-monitor

I have Azure nodejs Function which deployed as docker container in Function App service. Is there some way to store STDOUT logs from this function to Azure Monitor Logs (For example in AWS I can store stdout logs from function in Cloudwatch). I really need to deploy the same approach in Azure.
Any ideas?

I am storing Function logs in filesystem, but it's really inconvenient.

Comment: please provide code what you have tried.

Comment: what type of STDOUT logs you want?

Answer (score 0):

To Get logs from function in Azure Monitor Logs. You need to link your application insights.

I have created a normal HttpTrigger named **"JSHttpTrigger"** in node.js function named **"stdoutlogs2"**.

if you are deploying locally you need to add **"APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"**
Settings in **"local.settings.json"** file which will be available in your function app directory in local.

```
"APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING":"InstrumentationKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/"
```

**local.settings.json:**

```
 {
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING":"InstrumentationKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/"
  }
}
```

In Azure portal you can create in **Environment variables->App settings**:

[image]

You can get **connection string** of the Application insights from the Azure portal.

**< Your Function>->Application Insights->**
as shown below:

[image]

[image]

**Note:-** ***You can select your existing application insights (if you have) during your Function creation. Otherwise it will create a new application insights with its own default workspace. As you can see in previous images***

As you can see, I have printed my output in logs.
**Output:**

[image]

To
put your required STDOUT in logs, it should be inside **context.log** in your code.

```
context.log(<your output>);
```

You can open application insights with logs
directly from monitor section of your function by clicking **"Run your query in Application Insights"**:

**Same output in logs:**

[image]

As you can see it is saved in logs, from logs you can use it as per your requirement:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I need to understand to be able to use Application Insights and logs workspace I have to use Microsoft libraries in my nodejs code, right? I am looking for some way to do it without Microsoft libraries. Is it possible to capture logs via console.log() statement instead of context.log(). Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can capture logs via `console.log()` statement instead of `context.log()`.